# FormData() coudn't extract form parameters from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, post

I have written a jQuery function whose purpose is to extract parameters from a form upon submitting it. To extract form data, I am using the function FormData() function. After that, I have also written a loop to print the form entries, but nothing is getting printed in the console.

My HTML form:

```
<div class="form-contact">
        <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" class="contact-form" method="post" novalidate>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                  <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                  <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
                  <label>Email Address<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                  <p class="help-block"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row control-group">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12  controls">
              <label>Subject</label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" id="subject">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row control-group">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 controls">
              <label>Message<span>*</span></label>
              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
              <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="success"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 text-right">
              <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>enter code here
```

My JS file:

```
$(function() {

$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        /*var email = $("input#email").val();
        var subject = $("input#subject").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();*/
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message*/
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message

        var dat=new FormData($('#contactForm')[0]);
        if(firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        for (var pair of dat.entries())
        {
          console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/signup",
            data: dat,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            /*{
                name: name,
                subject: subject,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },*/
            //cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                console.log(error);
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

// $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
//     e.preventDefault();
//     $(this).tab("show");
// });
});
```

Comment: `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/signup",
            data: dat,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false` , where `data: dat` came from?

Comment: `var dat=new FormData($('contactForm')[0]);` should be this `var dat=new FormData($('#contactForm')[0]);`. The problem is your selector.

Comment: I have tried using #contactForm but it still doesn't work .In the JS console "button, " this gets printed .

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get all the form parameters on client side

Var dat = $(this).serializeArray();
//this contains object of form submitted

For(Var i=0;i

//serializeArray returns an array of parameters which are not disabled and have name attribute

Comment: No, I don't want to take the hectic of JSON objects again.